# tidyr::pivot_wider() duplicate values to new row without duplicating other values in row

Tags: r

I need to `pivot_wider` my dataset.  There are duplicate values that I would like to add to a new row (rather than having the duplicate values show as a list).  The code below is how I tried to accomplish this.  Using this code, the listed items move to a new column, but the other values in that row are duplicated.

```
df = data.frame(variables = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
                values = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                dates = c(6, 6, 6, 6))

df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variables,
              values_from = values,
              values_fill = NA,
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  dates     a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     1     2     3
2     6     1     2     4
```

Desired Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  dates     a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     1     2     3
2     NA    NA    NA    4
```

**UPDATE**

Using the answers below, I was able to get close to what I needed.

Here is a more complex dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(RK = c(1,1,1,1,
                        1,1,1,1,
                        1,2,2,2,
                        1,2,2,3,
                        3,3,3,3,
                        3,3,3,4,
                        4,4,5,5,
                        6,6,6,6,
                        7,7,7,7),
                 Name = paste0("Name", seq(1:36)),
                 Position = rep(paste("POS", seq(1:4)),9))

# Code
df %>% 
  mutate(cnt = row_number(), .by = Position) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Position, 
              values_from = Name) %>%
  select(-cnt) %>%
  arrange(RK)

# Result
# A tibble: 14 × 5
      RK `POS 1` `POS 2` `POS 3` `POS 4`
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1     1 Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4  
 2     1 Name5   Name6   Name7   Name8  
 3     1 Name9   NA      NA      NA     
 4     1 Name13  NA      NA      NA     
 5     2 NA      Name10  Name11  Name12 
 6     2 NA      Name14  Name15  NA     
 7     3 NA      NA      NA      Name16 
 8     3 Name17  Name18  Name19  Name20 
 9     3 Name21  Name22  Name23  NA     
10     4 NA      NA      NA      Name24 
11     4 Name25  Name26  NA      NA     
12     5 NA      NA      Name27  Name28 
13     6 Name29  Name30  Name31  Name32 
14     7 Name33  Name34  Name35  Name36
```

**Remaining issue**
For RK == 3, I want to shift the results so row 1 of RK ==3 contains all of the names and the NAs for that row appear after the names.  So in this example, RK ==3 would only require 2 rows of names instead of 3 and RK == 4 would only require 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your more complicated example, you need to group_by RK and Position to get your described outcome, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(RK = c(1,1,1,1,
                        1,1,1,1,
                        1,2,2,2,
                        1,2,2,3,
                        3,3,3,3,
                        3,3,3,4,
                        4,4,5,5,
                        6,6,6,6,
                        7,7,7,7),
                 Name = paste0("Name", seq(1:36)),
                 Position = rep(paste("POS", seq(1:4)),9))

df %>%
  group_by(RK, Position) %>%
  mutate(cnt = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Position, 
              values_from = Name) %>%
  select(-cnt) %>%
  arrange(RK)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#> # Groups:   RK [7]
#>       RK `POS 1` `POS 2` `POS 3` `POS 4`
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1     1 Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4  
#>  2     1 Name5   Name6   Name7   Name8  
#>  3     1 Name9   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#>  4     1 Name13  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#>  5     2 <NA>    Name10  Name11  Name12 
#>  6     2 <NA>    Name14  Name15  <NA>   
#>  7     3 Name17  Name18  Name19  Name16 
#>  8     3 Name21  Name22  Name23  Name20 
#>  9     4 Name25  Name26  <NA>    Name24 
#> 10     5 <NA>    <NA>    Name27  Name28 
#> 11     6 Name29  Name30  Name31  Name32 
#> 12     7 Name33  Name34  Name35  Name36
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does that solve your problem? Or are there further 'tweaks' you want to make?

Comment: I just tried this method, but it doesn't seem to work if the columns are strings rather than numbers.  Am I missing something or is that correct?

Comment: You need additional changes to get your desired outcome; I'll edit my answer @melmo

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution may be to create a row number using `dplyr::row_number()` within `mutate()` then `pivot_wider`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(cnt = row_number(), .by = variables) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variables, 
              values_from = values) %>%
  select(-cnt)
```

Output:

```
  dates     a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     1     2     3
2     6    NA    NA     4
```

The only difference here and your desired output is that `dates` has values throughout, which from my perspective seems logical. However, if you wanted all subsequent instances to be `NA`, you could simply add an additional `mutate`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(cnt = row_number(), .by = variables) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variables, 
              values_from = values) %>%
  mutate(dates = case_when(cnt == 1 ~ dates)) %>% 
  select(-cnt)
```

Output

```
  dates     a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     1     2     3
2    NA    NA    NA     4
```

Comment: Thank you - this gets me really close, but with a more complex dataset (updated my question to include this dataset instead), the rows don't quite align correctly.  Any thoughts?